# Detect when ScrollView frame is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-scrollview

I create frames like this. The number can change throughout runtime.

```
for (i in (1..numStations(serverText)))// number of frames
{
    frame = ScrollView(this@HomeActivity) 
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_layout, frame) 
    frame.tag = i.toString()  
    gridRoot.addView(frame)
}
```

frame_layout is FrameLayout with some images and texts. I have set focusable and clickable to true on FrameLayout. So I want to detect when a frame is clicked and which one (I added tags starting with 1).

Comment: Its better if you use RecyclerView instead. Better in the long run

Comment: How difficult is it to change from ScrollView to RecyclerView? I'm having some trouble.

Comment: i suggest that you make a mockup app first that uses the RecyclerView. ScrollView is good for some occasions, but using it with data is kinda off.